# Grails Having issues with form submission

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

Rendering the params and gets all the data I submit

```
["address.address1":"reston1", "address":["address1":"reston1", "county":"fairfax", "zipcode":"20190", "address2":"reston2", "city":"reston"], "representative.telephone":"7702438000", "representative":["telephone":"7702438000", "fax":"7702438001"], "address.county":"fairfax", "address.zipcode":"20190", "user.lastName":"Chinthalapudi", "user":["lastName":"Chinthalapudi", "password":"spring", "email":"srinv9@gmail.com", "firstName":"Srinivas", "userName":"srisris"], "address.address2":"reston2", "create":"Create", "user.password":"spring", "user.email":"srinv9@gmail.com", "representative.fax":"7702438001", "user.firstName":"Srinivas", "user.userName":"srisris", "address.city":"reston", "company.companyName":"ATS", "company":["companyName":"ATS"], "action":"register", "controller":"employerRegistration"]
```

Error Stack

```
Field error in object 'com.srisris.wr.User' on field 'email': rejected value [null]; codes [com.srisris.wr.User.email.nullable.error.com.srisris.wr.User.email,com.srisris.wr.User.email.nullable.error.email,com.srisris.wr.User.email.nullable.error.java.lang.String,com.srisris.wr.User.email.nullable.error,user.email.nullable.error.com.srisris.wr.User.email,user.email.nullable.error.email,user.email.nullable.error.java.lang.String,user.email.nullable.error,com.srisris.wr.User.email.nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.email,com.srisris.wr.User.email.nullable.email,com.srisris.wr.User.email.nullable.java.lang.String,com.srisris.wr.User.email.nullable,user.email.nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.email,user.email.nullable.email,user.email.nullable.java.lang.String,user.email.nullable,nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.email,nullable.email,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [email,class com.srisris.wr.User]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]Field error in object 'com.srisris.wr.User' on field 'firstName': rejected value [null]; codes [com.srisris.wr.User.firstName.nullable.error.com.srisris.wr.User.firstName,com.srisris.wr.User.firstName.nullable.error.firstName,com.srisris.wr.User.firstName.nullable.error.java.lang.String,com.srisris.wr.User.firstName.nullable.error,user.firstName.nullable.error.com.srisris.wr.User.firstName,user.firstName.nullable.error.firstName,user.firstName.nullable.error.java.lang.String,user.firstName.nullable.error,com.srisris.wr.User.firstName.nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.firstName,com.srisris.wr.User.firstName.nullable.firstName,com.srisris.wr.User.firstName.nullable.java.lang.String,com.srisris.wr.User.firstName.nullable,user.firstName.nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.firstName,user.firstName.nullable.firstName,user.firstName.nullable.java.lang.String,user.firstName.nullable,nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.firstName,nullable.firstName,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [firstName,class com.srisris.wr.User]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]Field error in object 'com.srisris.wr.User' on field 'lastName': rejected value [null]; codes [com.srisris.wr.User.lastName.nullable.error.com.srisris.wr.User.lastName,com.srisris.wr.User.lastName.nullable.error.lastName,com.srisris.wr.User.lastName.nullable.error.java.lang.String,com.srisris.wr.User.lastName.nullable.error,user.lastName.nullable.error.com.srisris.wr.User.lastName,user.lastName.nullable.error.lastName,user.lastName.nullable.error.java.lang.String,user.lastName.nullable.error,com.srisris.wr.User.lastName.nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.lastName,com.srisris.wr.User.lastName.nullable.lastName,com.srisris.wr.User.lastName.nullable.java.lang.String,com.srisris.wr.User.lastName.nullable,user.lastName.nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.lastName,user.lastName.nullable.lastName,user.lastName.nullable.java.lang.String,user.lastName.nullable,nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.lastName,nullable.lastName,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [lastName,class com.srisris.wr.User]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]Field error in object 'com.srisris.wr.User' on field 'password': rejected value [null]; codes [com.srisris.wr.User.password.nullable.error.com.srisris.wr.User.password,com.srisris.wr.User.password.nullable.error.password,com.srisris.wr.User.password.nullable.error.java.lang.String,com.srisris.wr.User.password.nullable.error,user.password.nullable.error.com.srisris.wr.User.password,user.password.nullable.error.password,user.password.nullable.error.java.lang.String,user.password.nullable.error,com.srisris.wr.User.password.nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.password,com.srisris.wr.User.password.nullable.password,com.srisris.wr.User.password.nullable.java.lang.String,com.srisris.wr.User.password.nullable,user.password.nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.password,user.password.nullable.password,user.password.nullable.java.lang.String,user.password.nullable,nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.password,nullable.password,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [password,class com.srisris.wr.User]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]Field error in object 'com.srisris.wr.User' on field 'userName': rejected value [null]; codes [com.srisris.wr.User.userName.nullable.error.com.srisris.wr.User.userName,com.srisris.wr.User.userName.nullable.error.userName,com.srisris.wr.User.userName.nullable.error.java.lang.String,com.srisris.wr.User.userName.nullable.error,user.userName.nullable.error.com.srisris.wr.User.userName,user.userName.nullable.error.userName,user.userName.nullable.error.java.lang.String,user.userName.nullable.error,com.srisris.wr.User.userName.nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.userName,com.srisris.wr.User.userName.nullable.userName,com.srisris.wr.User.userName.nullable.java.lang.String,com.srisris.wr.User.userName.nullable,user.userName.nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.userName,user.userName.nullable.userName,user.userName.nullable.java.lang.String,user.userName.nullable,nullable.com.srisris.wr.User.userName,nullable.userName,nullable.java.lang.String,nullable]; arguments [userName,class com.srisris.wr.User]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
```

My domain classes

```
package com.srisris.wr

class User {

    String userName
    String password
    //String passwordConfirm
    String firstName
    String lastName
    String email

    static mapping = {
        tablePerHierarchy false
    }
    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

package com.srisris.wr

```
class Representative extends User{
    static belongsTo = [ company: Company ]



    String jobTitle
    String telephone
    String fax

    static constraints = {

    }
}


package com.srisris.wr

class Employer extends User {
     Address address

    static constraints = {

    }

}

package com.srisris.wr

class Employee extends User{
     Address address

    static constraints = {

    }
}


package com.srisris.wr

class Company {

    String companyName
    Address address
    String companyRegistration
    int totalEmployeeStrength
    int numberOfUkPAYEEmployees
    String category
    Representative representative
    Bank bank



    static constraints = {

    }
}


package com.srisris.wr

class Bank {
    static belongsTo = [ company: Company ]
   // static belongsTo = [ retailer: Retailer ]
    Company company

    static constraints = {

    }
}


package com.srisris.wr

class Address {

   static belongsTo = [ user: User,company: Company ]
    //static belongsTo = [ company: Company]
    User user
    String address1
    String address2
    String city
    //String state
    String county
    String zipcode

    Company company

    static constraints = {

    }
}
```

My Controller

package com.srisris.wr.register.employer
    import com.srisris.wr.User

```
class EmployerRegistrationController {

    def index = { }

    def register={
        render params

        User user= new User(params)
        user.save()

        if(user.hasErrors()){
            user.errors.allErrors.each {
                render it
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My GSP

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="pl">
  <head>
    <title>Workriders - Employer Registration page - JustProto</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <g:form action="register" method="post" >

        <table width="80%" height="60%" align="left">
          <tr><th align="right"><g:message code="Your Company Name"/></th><td><g:textField name="company.companyName"></g:textField></td></tr>
          <tr><th align="right"><g:message code="Address"/></th> <td><g:textField name="address.address1" ></g:textField></td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td><g:textField name="address.address2"></g:textField></td></tr>
          <tr><th align="right"><g:message code="Town/City"/></th><td><g:textField name="address.city" ></g:textField></td></tr>
          <tr><th align="right"><g:message code="County"/></th><td><g:textField name="address.county" ></g:textField></td></tr>
          <tr><th align="right"><g:message code="PostCode"/></th><td><g:textField name="address.zipcode" ></g:textField></td></tr>
          <tr><th align="right"><g:message code="First Name"/></th><td align="left"><g:textField name="user.firstName"></g:textField></td></tr>
          <tr><th align="right"><g:message code="Last Name"/></th><td><g:textField name="user.lastName"></g:textField></td></tr>
          <tr><th align="right"><g:message code="Telephone"/></th> <td><g:textField name="representative.telephone" ></g:textField></td></tr>
          <tr><th align="right"><g:message code="Fax"/></th><td><g:textField name="representative.fax" ></g:textField></td></tr>
          <tr><th align="right"><g:message code="Email"/></th><td><g:textField name="user.email" ></g:textField></td></tr>
          <tr><th align="right"><g:message code="User Name"/></th><td><g:textField name="user.userName"></g:textField></td></tr>
          <tr><th align="right"><g:message code="password"/></th><td><g:passwordField name="user.password" ></g:passwordField></td></tr>

          <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td> <g:submitButton name="create" value="Create"/></td></tr>          
        </table>
      </div>
    </g:form>

  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As the stacktrace point out, that error happens because the `email` field of user is null.

It means `User user= new User(params)` fails. That's because you give the wrong parameters to initialize a User, for example, "User class" does not have "address" property. You should `new Employer()` instead.

Comment: But if you see the params which I am rendering just before insertion it prints out all the parameters I am supplying, I changed to Employer and still gets the field errors, somehow the values are getting null. But I do pass the values

Comment: @srisris: yes, the values are still got, but in wrong format. Since your domain is fairly complex, I recommend you set properties of Employer by hand in controller before saving.

Comment: Changing to Employer is correct. Next, in the GSP, try changing user.email to email.  The bind should then work as email is an attribute in Employer (via inheritance from User).

Comment: Thanks Paul for the clear explanation. The same applies for other attributes.

Answer (score 0):

GORM set `nullable: false` as a default constraint for each field of a domain. So when you save a row in the domain, because of `nullable:false` you given error will uccor. To solve this problem, one way is to set `nullable:true` as a default constraint of GORM. You can set this in your Config.groovy

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
   '*'(nullable:true, blank:true)
}
```

When u need to set `nullable:true` for any field u will set it in the domain class manually.